# PHP - Is it possible to hash an array of numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, numbers, sha256

I am currently working on setting up a number hashing system for a client. If I hash the numbers one by one with ***hash('sha256', $number)*** I can then insert them into a database and look them up correctly later on with no problems.

If I send an array of numbers such as: ***(1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045)*** through the same hash ***('sha256', $array)*** the output does not match up to the output I get when done one by one. Is there a particular reason this happens? Is it a bad idea to hash arrays?

Code example

If I pass the number 1031 by itself as follows I will get: 3e34b5dc434bcf3186f089d362691cfac1b17231601f2f402dc79015be878d83

```
$number = 1031;
$hash = hash('sha256', $number);
```

If the number 1031 gets passed through the following hash the result I get is: d83e4573f6d32ca3f17b77046809c1effe3b462b4cd7338d2c80568e63c76599

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $numbers = $row['pnumbers'];
     $hash = hash('sha256', $numbers);
 }
```

So I guess my question boils down to: Is it possible to hash multiple numbers at one time and retrieve the same output as if I were to hash them one by one? Or am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's impossible without a for(each) loop. What do you suspect the output will be, an array that contains the hashes? [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) you can find the documentation of the hash-function